# Blender Three.js exporter multy object with animations

Tags: three.js, blender

I create 2 simple objects in blender each of them has one bone and very simple animation, it works fine but when I try to export them to a JSON file using the latest io_three exporter in the dev library , if I choose to export the pose frames blender copy the key frames from one object to the other and delete the other keys and makes their positions the same, but if I set the export key frames option to rest it does not do that.
is this a bug in the exporter or it is not allowed to export more than one mesh with animations?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use MD5 file format, it is supported by blender and easy to import and supported by AssimpLib